# If a Jew broke Shabbos to safely store something, does that item become prohibited?

Tags: halacha, shabbat

A Jew is traveling before shabbos with a bag of valuables and has no place to store them safely. Finally, it's two minutes before sunset, so he just ditches the bag along the side of the road.

A non-Shabbos-observant Jew finds out about this, drives out on Shabbos, brings the bag home someplace safe, and then returns it to the first fellow after Shabbos.

Is the bag of valuables now prohibited to the first fellow because it is the product of breaking Shabbos?

Comment: We generally hold that a non shabbos observant jew in today's day and age is shogeg, so do you want an answer based around that, or are you talking more theory of gemara times etc

Comment: @rabbi is one allowed to benefit from the melacha of a shogeg done for one's sake, and would it make a difference if one asked him to take it, but didn't expect him to come in shabbos itself

Comment: @B''HBi'ezras--BoruchHashem generally speaking, a Jew can benefit from the melacha another Jew did on shabbat, after shabbat ends. There are certain exceptions, such as planting etc. It's complicated and hard to generalise. If this were a real situation, one should probably CLYOR

Comment: The rabbonom of crown heights never answer things seriously